# Create Multiple Inbox' Style Interface in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I use Gmail for my personal email and within that I use Multiple Inbox's as a task manager. Here's a blog post on this set up: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/gmail-multiple-inboxes/

The idea is that you can group your email into categories and show them on the same screen. I really like this set up and it helps me manage my life by staying on top of email and using Gmail almost like a task management tool.

I would like to mimic this with Outlook since my new employer uses Outlook but I'm struggling to do so. I created new categories and then:

Organize > arrange by > categories

If I then categorize some emails into the different categories, Outlook groups them together at the top, which is the desired result.

However, for some reason, after grouping by category, my non categorized emails, including unread emails, are sorted by oldest not newest, so new emails appear near to the bottom and not the top.

I would like to sort by category and then by date received, but it looks like I can only sort by one dimension at a time.

Is there a way to sort by category while still sorting email by date?

Outlook for Mac version 16.14.1

Comment: To my knowledge, this is possible in Outlook for Windows, but no similar option in Outlook for Mac 2016.

Comment: Ah really? Well, I hope they roll it out for Mac. I wonder if it's possible within browser?

Comment: Category is an Outlook client feature. I'm not sure whether Gmail provides a similar feature. To suggest Microsoft to roll this out for Mac, you can submit a feature request to them via: https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293343-outlook-for-mac